# How is this static singleton member getting set in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, static-members

I just did an Analyze of code that I use from a public library, and XCode pointed out a problem with the line that begins with [[[self alloc]:

```
static MyClass *_sharedInstance = nil;

+ (MyClass*)sharedInstance
{
    if (_sharedInstance != nil) {
        return _sharedInstance;
    }

    @synchronized(self) {
        if (_sharedInstance == nil) {
            [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
        }
    }

    return _sharedInstance;
}
```

As I look at this line, I have no idea how it is possible for _sharedInstance to ever get assigned. Can anyone explain to me why this code works? I would have expected that you need to write:

```
_sharedInstance = [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Comment: Does `MyClass` override `alloc`?  Also it shoudn't be `autorelease` so that looks broken.

Comment: not at all. this is a bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be set in `alloc`, rather than init. This would prevent creation of another instance in a recursive call from within `init`.

Explanation:

It's common for complex singletons to do a lot of setup. This setup could be complex, touching more than only this class. It happens that the singleton is requested from (deep) within this setup. If the `_sharedInstance` variable would not be set *before* calling `init`, two instances would be created.

Comment: You were right! This dude was setting it in allocWithZone. I had never seen that before as a design pattern...weird.

Comment: @esilver: because that's an antipattern (to be nice about it!). For your own singletons, follow bbum's advice, below.

Answer (score 3):

This is yet another example of way overthinking a `+sharedInstance` method to the point where it is confusing, at best, and only works because of other shenanigans (like overriding `release`).

Just do this and be done with it:

```
+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static MyClass *sharedInstance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Simple, straightforward, and does not preclude using `MyClass` as a non-singleton.   The one flaw in this is if `+sharedInstance` is called recursively, it'll deadlock, but `+sharedInstance` recursively is generally a bad sign anyway.